# jqGrid method for posting specific cell

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid with a method that calculates a value depending on different cells in the row.
I then set a specific cell to contain this value:

```
  $("#gridID").setCell(rowid, "Cell_Name", myCalculatedValue);
```

I then want to finalize this by saving the value to the database but I cannot seem to find a method for this.
Basically what I want is

```
$("#gridID").saveCellToDataBase(rowid, "Cell_Name");
```

Since this cell is not the cell edited but a calculated value due to another cell being edited it's not saved by default.

I was hoping that methods that could solve my problem would be:

```
$("#gridID").jqGrid("saveRow", rowid, true);
```

or

```
$("#gridID").saveCell(rowid, "Cell_Name");
```

But none of these methods seem to do what I want.

Comment: I dealt with the problem by gathering all the data and making an ajax call, still tho, I would be interested to see a jqGrid solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you try to post a data to the server, but one (or more) field(s) is not editable and depend on calculation of other fields something like Quantity*UnitPrice.

As you know the not editable  fields are not posted to the server and hence they can not be saved. In order to make this happen I see here two possible solutions.

1. Make the calculations at the server, without to post this value from jqGrid
2. Calculate the value in jqGrid and post it to the server

All of these have pro and cons, and I suppose that you can not make this calculation at server.

To post additional value to the server from editing depend on the editing method used - form edit, inline edit or cell edit.

Below I will describe a possible solution with inline edit and as exercise you will find it for other methods.

In jqGrid there is mechanism to post to post what you want to the server again with the edited fields. In our terms we name it serialization. This serialization happen before posting the data to the server and have different names depending on the editing module.
In case of inline edit this event is called **serializeRowData** and it is a grid parameter and not a parameter to the event.

In your case the code should like this:

```
$("jqGrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    serializeRowData : function( data ) {
    // suppose you have Qty and Unit field and want to post Total = Qty*Unit

        if(data.Qty && data.Unit) {
            data.Total = data.Qty*data.Unit;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Note the return at end of serializeRowData.
So this event execute every time you call saveRow, but this is well described in Guriddo [documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing)